# Всплывающая панель WPF

Tags: wpf

Добрый день. Как реализовать в проекте WPF по нажатии на кнопку всплывающую панель с изображениями. Имена файлов изображений загружаются в массив строк из определенной папки.

Comment: Панель где выезжает? Внутри окна? Нарисуйте эскиз того, что вы хотите получить.

Comment: @АндрейNOP выезжающая панель должно быть рядом с нажатой кнопкой (под ней).

Comment: Ничего не понятно все равно. Эскизы того что до нажатия и после него покажите.

Comment: Реализовал желаемый функционал с помощью элемента `popup`.

Comment: Отлично. Оформите ответ, будет интересно посмотреть.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выезжающую панель по нажатию на кнопку организовал через `Popup`:

```
<Button x:Name="bImages" Click="bImages_Click">
        <StackPanel x:Name="spbImages">
    <Image Source="SmileIcon.png" MaxHeight="25"/>
        <Popup x:Name="popupImages" Width="500" Height="200">
            <ListBox x:Name="lbImages" Width="500" Height="200" 
                     SelectionChanged="lbStikers_SelectionChanged" 
                     ItemTemplate="{StaticResource listTemplate}">
                <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <WrapPanel MaxWidth="500"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            </ListBox>
        </Popup>
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

`listTemplate` берет данные из класса в котором хранятся только пути к файлам изображений:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="listTemplate"> 
    <StackPanel>
        <Image Source="{Binding Path=ImageFile}" Height="50" Width="50"/>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Думаю конечно это не самый лучший вариант, но поставленную мою задачу выполняет.